# R: MaxEnt species distribution modeling with lapply -> args implicate different number of rows

Tags: r, rows, lapply, maxent, dismo

)

I want to apply dismo::maxent to a list of multiple datasets with lapply. But I get the error message that the arguments have a different number of rows, which is very strange because I created one dataset from the other one and they should have the same number of rows (which is proven via nrow()).

The fuction has the following structure:

```
maxent(x=dataFrame of environmental conditions at species locations (or background samples)
p=vector of 0 or 1 for species absence(0) or presence(1))
```

I tried:

```
me_lapply <- lapply(X=split_data_env_df, FUN=maxent, dummy_presence_list)
```

Where dummy_presence_list was generated by

```
dummy_presence_list <- list(rep(1, nrow(split_data_env_df[[1]])), rep(1, nrow(split_data_env_df[[2]])))
```

To summarize: I'm having two lists:

1. `split_data_env_df` which contains 2 data frames, (one with 3 rows, the second has 2 rows, each representing environmental variables at species locations) and 2 columns for each df (temperature and precipitation)

| t_mean | precip |  | t_mean2 | precip2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 |  | value7 | value8 |
| value3 | value4 |  | value9 | value10 |
| value5 | value6 |  |  |  |

2. `dummy_presence_list` which contains 2 vectors: c(1,1,1) and c(1,1) telling the maxent formula that environmental parameters from split_data mean that the species is present at those locations

And I want to use lapply to run maxent(x, p) on the first elements of each list `split_data_env_df` & `dummy_presence_list` and on the second elements of said lists

maxent function via lapply returns that the arguments don't have an equal number of rows: 3, 2

I think it has something to do with the way how the functions treat the data and not with the data itself since the number of rows is in fact the same. Note that this is only a reduced dataset for testing purposes. My actual dataset is much larger so it would be nice to get lapply working. Thank you :-)

Comment: I think you need `mapply` instead of `lapply`.  Something like `mapply(maxent,split_data_env_df,dummy_presence_list)`. However, take a look at the `mapply` documentation

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly :-)